# cca using vegan : no unconstrained inertia

Tags: r, vegan

I run a CCA analysis using vegan with 7500 sites, 9 species and 5 constrains variable. The results are 
>

```html
Call: cca(sitspe = Yp, sitenv = Xp)

            Inertia Proportion Rank
Total                              
Constrained  0.5051               6
Inertia is mean squared contingency coefficient 

Eigenvalues for constrained axes:
[1] 0.3317 0.1301 0.0328 0.0089 0.0014 0.0003
```

I don't understand why there is no unconstrained or total inertia?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your constrained axes explained everything, and no constrained inertia was left. How many axes did you get with unconstrained ordination (CCA without constraints)?

Your data are really non-square: matrix dimensions are 7500 times 9. There are only nine species, and if these are dependent or otherwise redundant, you may be able to explain everything with your constraints.